# Spring-data-elasticSearch: Limit of total fields [1000] in index [] has been exceeded,

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch version 3.0.8.RELEASE with elasticsearch 5.6.10.

When I reindex my entities, I encounter this exception

```
           Limit of total fields [1000] in index [Foo] has been exceeded
```

The index Foo is quite large, it contains about 60 field.
My idea to avoid this exception is to ignore fields unneeded for search. I tried to Mark these fields with

```
      @Field(store=false, index=false, type=...)
```

but I keep getting this exception.
Would you please help me